# Getting a field's actual type argument in annotation processing

Tags: java, annotation-processing

So I've been toying around with an annotation processor to generate some code for already generated java bean classes.

I've successfully found all of the fields in the annotated class and its superclasses, but have hit a wall. I want to also generate code for any types referenced from the annotated type.

```
private OtherType beanProperty;
```

I can get OtherType by getting all the fields in the annotated class and checking the kind of the element type

```
if (property.asType().getKind() == TypeKind.DECLARED) {
    propety.asType(); // "example.OtherType"
}
```

But If the bean property is:

```
private List<OtherType> beanProperty;
```

I can't get `OtherType` via the `VariableElement` definition of beanProperty.

```
if (types.isAssignable(property.asType(), COLLECTION)) {
    property.asType(); // "java.util.List"
    ((DeclaredType) property.asType()).getTypeArguments().get(0); // "E"
}
```

The result is the type variable of List, not the specific List in my field definition.

BUT, if I find the setter for beanProperty, and get the parameters of the setter:

```
ExecutableElement ee = (ExecutableElement) setter;
for (VariableElement tpe: ee.getParameters()) {
     tpe.asType(); // "java.util.List<example.OtherType>"
     (((DeclaredType) tpe.asType()).getTypeArguments().get(0); // "example.OtherType"
}
```

Is there something profound I'm missing here? Or is this perhaps even the right approach?

Comment: You are aware of generic [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), aren't you?

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes, but I'm asking because this is compile time, not runtime. I tried googling around for a definitive answer but could not find information.

Comment: What do you mean this is compile time? You said that you don't get the types when you run those code snippets, didn't you? Or are you getting a compile error?

Comment: Annotation processing happens before type erasure, this information should be available and it is, on the setter parameter, but not on the field definition for some reason. I want to know the reason, or if I'm using the confusing api wrong.

Comment: Seems like you somehow got a `Type` for the `List` class itself in your hands and not the specific type use `List<OtherType>`. It'd help to see your code for obtaining the variable element; Just had a quick try and could get the actual type parameter from a list field.